# Python Syntax Error in p++ compilation and setup

Tags: python, py++

I am trying to port py++ to the latest version of python and I came across the following piece of code it is complaining about. I am new to python. Any help is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

The error:

```
File "C:\tp\python\python34\Lib\site-packages\pyplusplus\gui\wizard.py", line
40
    , 'include_paths' : `self._parser_configuration.include_paths`
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code is below:

```
"""generates Py++ code from the user data"""

CODE_TEMPLATE = \
"""
import os
from pyplusplus import module_builder

#Creating an instance of class that will help you to expose your declarations
mb = module_builder.module_builder_t( [r"%(file_path)s"]
                                      , gccxml_path=r"%(gccxml_path)s" 
                                      , working_directory=r"%(working_dir)s"
                                      , include_paths=%(include_paths)s
                                      , define_symbols=%(define_symbols)s )


#Well, don't you want to see what is going on?
mb.print_declarations()

#Creating code creator. After this step you should not modify/customize declarations.
mb.build_code_creator( module_name='pyplusplus' )

#Writing code to file.
mb.write_module( './bindings.cpp' )
"""

class wizard_t( object ):
    """code generator that creates Py++ code"""
    def __init__( self
                  , parser_configuration
                  , source_file ):
        object.__init__( self )
        self._parser_configuration = parser_configuration
        self._source_file = source_file

    def create_code( self ):
        global CODE_TEMPLATE
        return CODE_TEMPLATE % {
            'gccxml_path' : self._parser_configuration.gccxml_path
            , 'working_dir' : self._parser_configuration.working_directory
            , 'include_paths' : `self._parser_configuration.include_paths`
            , 'define_symbols' : `self._parser_configuration.define_symbols`
            , "file_path" : `self._source_file`
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using backticks around those paths? Those backticks only work in Python 2 and can better be replaced with `repr()` calls.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is not my code. It is part of py++ a c++ to python code generator using boost python. I am learning python as I am trying to install this tool. I really do not know python well enough to have figured it out.

Comment: Evidently the code was written for Python 2. Using backticks instead of `repr()` is pretty obscure though (one of the reasons why the syntax was dropped from the language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Python 2 syntax; the backticks around the values are not supported in Python 3:

```
`self._parser_configuration.include_paths`
```

You'd have to use the `repr()` function there instead:

```
repr(self._parser_configuration.include_paths)
```

Backticks (documented as a [*string conversion* expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#string-conversions) are a pretty obscure and little used Python 2 syntax; your code is probably written with Python 2 in mind. There may be other Python-2-specific syntax in your codebase.